# Combining two for loops into one

Tags: java, for-loop, performance

I'm trying to find a better way to execute this method.

```
private void appendTiles(StringBuilder builder, String taggedRefData) {
    for (List<Line> column : columns) {
        for (Line line : column) {
            builder.append(line.link).append(line.text);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: **taggedRefData** is not used.

Comment: Try posting this on CodeReview.

Comment: Possible optimizations are possible if you reconsider the selection of the data structure. In fact program optimizations are so often about data structures. And don't stop while looking at `columns` also reconsider how usefull this string appender actually is. Maybe you can write directly to a stream? Or work with the input type....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to optimize this further in a meaningful way: the code of `appendTiles` must walk all `Line` objects inside `columns`, despite the fact that the actual objects are inside a two-dimensional structure (a collection of `List`s). One way or the other, you have to access `line.link` and `line.text`. This is the "payload" of the method; it is not going to change, even if you manage to combine two loops into one by using streams.

Answer (score 2):

No, you have a list of lists, there will always be two loops. Even in Java 8 you could use streams and flatMap, which would still use 2 loops, just internally.